# using double for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Does anyone see any syntax error on the following line?

```
int a6[3][2]={{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}};
for (int c=0 ; c<3 ; for(int c2=0 ; c2<2 ; cout<<a6[c++][c2++])) ;
```

It gives the following syntax error:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'for'
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` command is not an expression that you can use for the post-increment part of another `for`. Put it outside the control statements of the loop.

The code gets more readable if you keep with the common convention on how to write a loop, i.e. the code controlling the loop inside the `for` statement and the work to be done after it:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
  for(int c2 = 0; c2 < 2; c2++) {
    cout << a6[c][c2];
  }
}
```

This also fixes the bug that you have in your code, i.e. that you are incrementing `c` for every value that you show, while you should only increment it for every second value that you show.

Comment: I tried to make it work with a single for loop. Like: for(int c2 = 0; c2 < 2; cout << a6[c][c2++]);
  Thanks for your help

Comment: @user: You can do it with a single for loop also: `for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) cout << a6[c / 2][c % 2];`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a for statement in c is

```
for ( <expression> ; <expression> ; <expression> )
    <statement>
```

In your usage what should be the third expression of the first `for` is not an expression but a statement, which is not accepted syntax.

Comment: No you can't.  The language designers decided what is an expression in their language, and they decided this isn't.